# infinispan server fails to start when adding serialization configuration

Tags: java, keycloak, infinispan

extending infinispan configuration with a configmap on kubernetes
I have the following configuration:

```html
<infinispan>
  <cache-container>
    <serialization marshaller="org.infinispan.commons.marshall.JavaSerializationMarshaller">
      <allow-list>
        <class>org.keycloak.cluster.infinispan.WrapperClusterEvent</class>
        <class>java.time.Instant</class>
        <regex>.*</regex>
      </allow-list>
    </serialization>
  </cache-container>
</infinispan>
```

I checked several times and my ispn starts normally without the serialization tag and using other tags such as replicated-cache-configuration works and pods start normally,
so I know that the serialization tag is the culprit but I can't understand why
https://infinispan.org/docs/13.0.x/titles/encoding/encoding.html#adding-deserialization-allowlist_marshaller-implementations
am I missing something from the docs?

the error:

```
15:49:13,130 FATAL (main) [org.infinispan.SERVER] ISPN080028: Infinispan Server failed to start org.infinispan.manager.EmbeddedCacheManagerStartupException: org.infinispan.commons.CacheConfigurationException: Error starting component org.infinispan.persistence.manager.PersistenceManager
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.internalStart(DefaultCacheManager.java:770)
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.start(DefaultCacheManager.java:734)
    at org.infinispan.server.SecurityActions.lambda$startCacheManager$1(SecurityActions.java:69)
    at org.infinispan.security.Security.doPrivileged(Security.java:56)
    at org.infinispan.server.SecurityActions.doPrivileged(SecurityActions.java:40)
    at org.infinispan.server.SecurityActions.startCacheManager(SecurityActions.java:72)
    at org.infinispan.server.Server.run(Server.java:398)
    at org.infinispan.server.Bootstrap.runInternal(Bootstrap.java:165)
    at org.infinispan.server.tool.Main.run(Main.java:98)
    at org.infinispan.server.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:50)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.infinispan.server.loader.Loader.run(Loader.java:106)
    at org.infinispan.server.loader.Loader.main(Loader.java:51)
Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheConfigurationException: Error starting component org.infinispan.persistence.manager.PersistenceManager
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.startWrapper(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:585)
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.access$700(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:30)
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl$ComponentWrapper.running(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:808)
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.startDependencies(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:635)
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.doStartWrapper(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:599)
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.startWrapper(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:577)
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.access$700(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:30)
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl$ComponentWrapper.running(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:808)
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.startDependencies(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:635)
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.doStartWrapper(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:599)
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.startWrapper(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:577)
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.access$700(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:30)
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl$ComponentWrapper.running(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:808)
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.startDependencies(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:635)
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.doStartWrapper(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:599)
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.startWrapper(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:577)
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.access$700(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:30)
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl$ComponentWrapper.running(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:808)
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.startDependencies(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:635)
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.doStartWrapper(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:599)
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.startWrapper(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:577)
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.access$700(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:30)
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl$ComponentWrapper.running(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:808)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.internalStart(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:354)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.start(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:250)
    at org.infinispan.factories.ComponentRegistry.start(ComponentRegistry.java:216)
    at org.infinispan.cache.impl.CacheImpl.start(CacheImpl.java:1014)
    at org.infinispan.cache.impl.AbstractDelegatingCache.start(AbstractDelegatingCache.java:512)
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.wireAndStartCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:714)
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.createCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:660)
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.internalGetCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:549)
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.getCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:517)
    at org.infinispan.security.actions.GetCacheAction.run(GetCacheAction.java:26)
    at org.infinispan.security.actions.GetCacheAction.run(GetCacheAction.java:14)
    at org.infinispan.security.Security.doPrivileged(Security.java:61)
    at org.infinispan.globalstate.impl.SecurityActions.doPrivileged(SecurityActions.java:30)
    at org.infinispan.globalstate.impl.SecurityActions.getCache(SecurityActions.java:39)
    at org.infinispan.globalstate.impl.GlobalConfigurationManagerImpl.start(GlobalConfigurationManagerImpl.java:104)
    at org.infinispan.globalstate.impl.CorePackageImpl$2.start(CorePackageImpl.java:60)
    at org.infinispan.globalstate.impl.CorePackageImpl$2.start(CorePackageImpl.java:48)
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.invokeStart(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:617)
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.doStartWrapper(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:608)
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.startWrapper(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:577)
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.access$700(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:30)
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl$ComponentWrapper.running(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:808)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.internalStart(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:354)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.start(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:250)
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.internalStart(DefaultCacheManager.java:766)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.infinispan.persistence.spi.PersistenceException: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 9801ED07
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:314)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:319)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1739)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1348)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.infinispan.persistence.spi.PersistenceException: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 9801ED07
    at org.infinispan.persistence.file.SingleFileStore.blockingStart(SingleFileStore.java:231)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1736)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 9801ED07
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:940)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:379)
    at org.infinispan.commons.marshall.CheckedInputStream.<init>(CheckedInputStream.java:18)
    at org.infinispan.commons.marshall.JavaSerializationMarshaller.objectFromByteBuffer(JavaSerializationMarshaller.java:52)
    at org.infinispan.commons.marshall.AbstractMarshaller.objectFromByteBuffer(AbstractMarshaller.java:82)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.core.impl.DelegatingUserMarshaller.objectFromByteBuffer(DelegatingUserMarshaller.java:63)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.protostream.impl.MarshallableUserObject$Marshaller.read(MarshallableUserObject.java:139)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.protostream.impl.MarshallableUserObject$Marshaller.read(MarshallableUserObject.java:100)
    at org.infinispan.protostream.impl.ProtobufTagMarshallerDelegate.unmarshall(ProtobufTagMarshallerDelegate.java:32)
    at org.infinispan.protostream.WrappedMessage.readMessage(WrappedMessage.java:539)
    at org.infinispan.protostream.WrappedMessage.read(WrappedMessage.java:351)
    at org.infinispan.protostream.ProtobufUtil.fromWrappedByteArray(ProtobufUtil.java:129)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.protostream.impl.AbstractInternalProtoStreamMarshaller.objectFromByteBuffer(AbstractInternalProtoStreamMarshaller.java:97)
    at org.infinispan.persistence.file.SingleFileStore.rebuildIndex(SingleFileStore.java:395)
    at org.infinispan.persistence.file.SingleFileStore.blockingStart(SingleFileStore.java:205)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: and I need to add the configuration because of getting this error Unexpected error: retrieving data. "ISPN000936: Class 'org.keycloak.cluster.infinispan.WrapperClusterEvent' blocked by deserialization allow list. Adjust the configuration serialization allow list regular expression to include this class."

Comment: You probably use some persistent store that was created using another serialization (protostream ?) and it can't be read now. Clearing and thus forcing the persistent store recreation could help.

However I can report that I'm unable to get past the ISPN000936 even with the properly working config and the desired classes on the allow-list. It appears that it doesn't work with clustered caches and media-type application/x-java-object (which is what I'd like to achieve in order to avoid serialization for local objects).

Comment: I ended not using an external infinispan server and instead just used keycloaks embedded infinispan feature that is easily configured. I'm not sure what are the ups and downs for this but atleast for now I can scale down and up multiple keycloak replicas, I can have a full restart of all of keycloak pods and won't lose sessions.